# Expanding treeview item on single click, not double

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written this code to try and override the treeview's default behaviour of expanding an item when it is either double clicked or you click on the item's toggle icon. This works on Python 3.9.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def toggle_expansion(event):
    tree = event.widget
    item_id = tree.selection()[0]
    tree.item(item_id, open=not treeview.item(item_id, 'open'))

root = tk.Tk()

treeview = ttk.Treeview(root)
treeview.pack()

parent1 = treeview.insert('', 'end', text='Parent', open=True)
parent2 = treeview.insert('', 'end', text='Parent 2', open=True)
treeview.insert(parent1, 'end', text='Child')
treeview.insert(parent2, 'end', text='Child 2')

treeview.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', toggle_expansion)

root.mainloop()
```

This works only when clicking the treeview item and not its toggle icon. I am guessing the event that handles the toggle icon is still firing after `toggle_expansion` finishes, reversing the items openness. Does anyone know if this is correct, and if so, how to override this behaviour?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are few ways to do what you want. I came up to an idea that is straight forward for me: Use the `identify_element(x, y)` function of `treeview`, which tells you which element is located at some **local** coordinates of the `treeview`. For example, clicking directly on a `label` it returns "*text*". If you click on the toggle icon, it returns "*Treeitem.indicator*". So, you can make your function do nothing if you click the toggle icon. here is how you can modify you function:

```
def toggle_expansion(event):
    tree: ttk.Treeview = event.widget
    item_id = tree.selection()[0]
    cursor_local_position = (tree.winfo_pointerx() - tree.winfo_rootx(),
                             tree.winfo_pointery() - tree.winfo_rooty())

    if tree.identify_element(*cursor_local_position) != 'Treeitem.indicator':
        tree.item(item_id, open=not treeview.item(item_id, 'open'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it introduces some syntax that is new to me (which is great). Is `tree: ttk.Treeview` some sort of class casting? I like this answer a lot, it is less hacky than one solution I found (I will post when I can). If anyone could explain why the code in OP doesn't work tho, I would be v grateful

Comment: `tree: ttk.Treeview` is a type hint. I use it to indicate that my variable should only be of this type and no other. You can read more about this yourself, for example [there](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).
Your code doesn't work for the reason you've said: When you click on the icon, an item is closed/opened by default, but your function then returns it back.

Comment: I said in a previous comment I would post a hack I did to get around this issue. There is no need, it adds nothing that the answerer didn't cover. Thus marked Danya's answer as accepted.